# what does inequality between traces of inverse of matrices imply?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite matrices. In which case
is the following relation correct please?

$$
Tr(A^{-1})\geq Tr(B^{-1})\implies Tr(A)\leq Tr(B),
$$
where $Tr(A)$ means the trace of the matrix $A$.

Comment: try some diagonal matrices, 2 by 2 and 3 by 3.

Comment: I am curious. Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: @Ralff, No, I have not found it yet.